# msi installer failing with error code 1618 in Azure DevOps

Tags: windows-installer

I'm running a release deployment in Azure DevOps that includes a command line task that executes an msi installer. The installer apparently fails, and the command line task returns: **##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1618'.** What could be going wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me turned out be be option 2 from [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-code-1618-when-trying-to-install-new/fb4e98b3-59d9-4cfd-916c-215502864bce). Somehow the Windows Installer service had stopped running, and needed restarting.

1. Press Windows key + R to open the run command.
2. Type services.msc and press enter.
3. Locate the *Windows Installer* service
4. Right click on the service and choose start.